# Tamron 24-70mm 2.8f What is the best Canon to go with?

Tags: tamron

I recently bought a tamron 24-70mm f2.8 for Canon, So I would like some advices to buy the best body for this lens.

I am doing wedding and nightclubs photography and my budget is around 2000$

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Is the Tamron 24-70mm a good wedding lens for a Canon 5DS r?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61994/is-the-tamron-24-70mm-a-good-wedding-lens-for-a-canon-5ds-r). See [MichaelT](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61994/is-the-tamron-24-70mm-a-good-wedding-lens-for-a-canon-5ds-r#comment107809_61994)'s comment.

Comment: Also, please see [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [this one](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). The problem is with this and your other question is it won't be useful in three or four years when someone else comes looking for it. You could reword it as "*What should I look for* in a body with X lens and I plan to take Y pictures with it?" That turns it into something more timeless.

Comment: The DxO optics site allows you to obtain a list of key parameters and an overall figure of merit of a given lens with a range of bodies. I find/found some of their results somewhat surprising and (for me) somewhat unintuitive. Reading their rationale for their rating system is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weddings & nightclubs (by virtue of the iffy lighting) would normally steer you toward a FF camera like the 6D, and that focal length range is well-suited to wide-normal use on a FF camera, as well, but you'll want to bear in mind that on a FF camera, you're just getting into what's considered an acceptable focal length for portraits at the telephoto end of that lens (85mm is usually considered about ideal).  Paired with a 70-200, however, you'd have a great combo for portraits and wider environmental shots.  There's a reason that pair is so popular.

I'd recommend looking through some of your existing photos to see what sort of focal length range you're using for your existing shots -- this might give you a better sense for your ideal lens and body.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "best body" for a given budget and to get a really good answer you have to provide a lot more information about your needs (what kind of photos are you planning to take, what other equipment do you have, do you have a camera body already etc.). Wedding and nightclubs are typical low light scenarios but you can use flash.

Go and try some bodies out and see with one that you enjoy the most. The reach of a 24-70 lens is probably best suited for a full frame camera, but it can be used with crop frame too.